# symlink mac from outside folder

Tags: macos, symlink

Imagine this is my folder structure

```
filepath\targetpath
filepath\folder1
```

I can create the symlink when I am inside the targetpath folder

```
ln -s ..\folder1 folder2
```

but when I try to create symlink from upper level with below command

```
ln -s filepath\folder1 filepath\targetpath\folder2
```

it create shortcut file rather than a symlink to filepath.

How can I create symlink when I am outside of the targetpath folder?

Comment: Unless you can add some sort of programming context, this type of question might work better on [Super User](http://superuser.com/)... :)

Comment: You have your slashes backwards. Pathnames are `dir/dir/dir/filename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a symbolic link is not an absolute pathname (begins with `/`) it is interpreted relative to the directory containing the link, *not* your cwd when you make the link. So if you do:

```
ln -s filepath/folder1 filepath/targetpath/folder2
```

the target of the link is `filepath/targetpath/filepath/folder1`. You should make the symlink the same way as you did the first time:

```
ln -s ../folder1 filepath/targetpath/folder2
```